# How to configure exim4 to orelay email from a specific IP?

Tags: windows, debian, email, smtp, exim

I am attempting to set up an SMTP relay server, using exim4. However, I have only one IP that I want to be allowed to send email through my server. Is this done using iptables or some configuration within exim?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your IP to the `relay_from_hosts` variable.

```
relay_from_hosts = : localhost : 1.2.3.4 : 2.3.4.5
```